# Find all functions that satisfy $f(x^2f(y)^2)=f(x)^2f(y)$.

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

Find all $f:\mathbb Q_{>0}\to \mathbb Q_{>0}$ such that $$f(x^2f(y)^2)=f(x)^2f(y)$$
This is from the IMO Shortlist 2018, and I just want to know if my solution is valid, here is the [official solution](https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2018SL.pdf)

set $x=1/f(y)^2$ we get $$f\left(\frac{1}{f(y)^2}\right)= f\left(\frac{1}{f(y)^2}\right)^2 f(y)$$

We can cancel these two because of the domain and the range of the $f$, which means $$f \left(\frac{1}{f(y)^2} \right)= \frac{1}{f(y)} $$
$$f(t)=\sqrt{t}$$
but that doesn’t satisfy the range of the function and it’s not even a solution to the functional equation.

Comment: On the right hand side you missed a square.

Comment: How do you deduce that $f(t)=\sqrt t$ ?  Keep in mind that the prior equality need not hold generally.   It only holds for $t=\frac 1{(f(y))^2}$ which may represent only a subset of the rationals. If, for instance $f(x)$ is identically $1$, which is obviously a valid solution to your problem, then your claimed equality only holds for a single value.

Comment: It holds for $1$ but now what can we say? @lulu

Comment: I don't know that your approach gets you much further.  Note that $\sqrt x$ is a perfectly valid solution save for the fact that it does not map rationals to rationals. If the problem had asked about reals to reals you'd have found a second solution. I assume that the condition on rationality is enough to force the thing to be identically $1$.

Comment: To be clear:  I don't know that your approach fails.  Maybe you can start with some value $x$ such that $f(x)\neq 1$ and derive a contradiction.  After all, even if $\sqrt x$ is rational, you can't iterate that (unless $f(x)$ is $1$).

Comment: You have not proven that the image of $f$ is $Q >  0 $, so your substitution isn't valid. $\quad$ Note also that $f(x) = 1 \forall x $ is a valid solution, which you didn't find. It doesn't contradict what you stated, since you couldn't substitute $ \forall t, \exists y $ such that $t = f(y)$

Comment: Are you talking about the first one? @CalvinLin

Comment: No, I'm taking about the final part. I edited my comment with a bit more details.   (For "cancel these two because of the domain and range" I guess you just mean "because $x, f(x)$ are not 0).

Answer (score 1):

(Not an answer) To elaborate on my comment, the mistake OP made in

> $$f \left(\frac{1}{f(y)^2} \right)= \frac{1}{f(y)} \Rightarrow f(t)=\sqrt{t} \, \forall t $$

is that the substitution of $ t = \frac{1}{f(y)^2}$ requires there to be a $y$ for that particular value of $t$.

EG If there are no solutions to $ f(y) ^ 2 = 4$, then we cannot conclude that $f( 0.25) = f( \frac{1}{4} ) = \frac{1}{2} $.

Thus, all that we have is

> If there is some $y$ such that $ t = \frac{1}{f(y)^2}$, then $f(t) = \sqrt{t}$.

Assuming that we can show $f(y) = 1$ for some $y$  (which is a big assumption, since the official solution doesn't seem to establish specific values), then we can conclude via this approach that indeed $f(1) = 1$.

Answer (score -1):

If we disregard the domain and range we see immediately that there are three trivial solutions

1. $f(x)=0$
2. $f(x)=1$
3. $f(x)=-1$

Of these, only the second satisfies the domain/range conditions.

So the only question is whether other solutions exist, since the original question asks for *all* solutions.

Your attempt does find another solution valid for domain/range $\mathbb{R}$ but not for $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$ so it, too, must be discarded.

But this still does not rule out other possible solutions.

The official solution takes care of this by showing that the solution must be of the form $f(x)=C$ where $C$ is a positive rational number and that it must be the case that $C=1$.

So $f(x)=1$ is indeed the only solution.